# Angular ng-repeat y ng-if pintar lineas

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Comunidad buenos días, como puedo pintar una determinada linea de un color, como para resaltar, según el valor de un campo,

```
dato1 dato2 dato3
xx    xx    0
xx    xx    0
xx    xx    1 --> resaltar todo la fila o cambiar de color
xx    xx    0
xx    xx    1 --> resaltar todo la fila o cambiar de color


<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="m in MarcacionesFuncionario">
        <td>{{m.marcado}}</td>
        <td>{{m.detalleClasificadorMarcacion.descripcionDetalleClasificador}}</td>                      
       <td>{{m.detalleClasificadorMarcador.descripcionDetalleClasificador}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

saludos cordiales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asigna una clase css a la fila si el dato coincide, para tu ejemplo supongamos como en el ejemplo que pones, que evaluaremos el atributo `dato3` usamos la directiva [NgClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
dato1 dato2 dato3
xx    xx    0
xx    xx    0
xx    xx    1 --> resaltar todo la fila o cambiar de color
xx    xx    0
xx    xx    1 --> resaltar todo la fila o cambiar de color
```

En el template seria lo siguiente

```
<tr ng-repeat="dato in datos"  ng-class="{'resaltado': dato.dato3 == 1}">
    <td> {{ dato.dato1 }}</td>  
    <td> {{ dato.dato2 }}</td>  
    <td> {{ dato.dato3 }}</td>  
</tr>
```

css

```
.resaltado { background-color: #00FF00; }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo completo http://jsfiddle.net/pg1b5jbq/

Comment: muchas gracias Ricardo, simple y sencillo, no ubicaba como usar el ng-class, un favor maestro, puedes darme alguna referencia de una buena guía para estos detalles de angular, saludos cordiales

Comment: Hola Cristian me alegro que te haya sido util, en cuanto a tu pedido mucho no te puedo ayudar no soy experto en AngularJS actualmente deje el desarrollo en AngularJS para pasar a Angular2, pero la url de la documentación oficial es bastante completa en cuanto a referencias